# configure:file not found while static linking Qt 5.4 project in linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt5.4

I have an application which i want to deploy using static linking.I am using Qt 5.4 and ubuntu.I learnt that to deploy my application i have to bulid qt statically using the following code

```
cd /path/to/Qt
./configure -static -prefix /path/to/Qt <other parameters>
make sub-src
```

i have Qt installed in home/Qt5.4.0

When i run the above code it says that

```
 configure:no such file
```

When i check the Qt directory there is indeed no configure file.I could only find

```
configure.prf
in Qt5.4.0/5.4/gcc_64/mkspecs/features/
```

this may be novice but how should i deploy my application now?

Answer (score 0):

I can describe steps I did for Windows.

1. Configure Qt static build. For this download source code and in e.g.     `d:\Qt\5.4\Src\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-g++\qmake.conf` change line `QMAKE_LFLAGS =` to `QMAKE_LFLAGS = -static -static-libgcc`. Then save and exit.
2. Make Qt. In console (preferably one from Qt folder like `Qt 5.4 for Desktop (MinGW 4.9 32 bit)` go to `d:\Qt\5.4\Src\qtbase`, change environment variables

   set LIB=
   set INCLUDE=
   SET QTDIR=D:\Qt\5.4\Src\qtbase
   SET QMAKESPEC=win32-g++
   SET PATH=C:\Python34;c:\Strawberry\perl\bin;d:\Qt\Tools\mingw491_32\bin;d:\Qt\5.4\Src\qtbase\bin;%PATH%

Start configuration (accept license) and make.

```
configure.exe -debug-and-release -opensource -c++11 -static -opengl desktop -no-angle -no-vcproj -nomake examples -nomake demos
mingw32-make.exe (This can take time)
```

3. Add kit in Qt Options (Build & Run tab)[image: Static kit screenshot]
4. Chose new kit for the project. Should work.